# Only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

I Have A Problem With My Code:

```
string yn = Console.ReadLine ();
int yes;
yn == "Y" ? (yes = 1) : (yes = 0);
```

And I Get:

> only assignment call increment decrement await and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

But I Dont Know What To Do!
Please Help!

Answer (score 7):

Change  `yn == "Y" ? (yes = 1) : (yes = 0);`

To this instead.

```
yes = yn == "Y" ? 1 : 0;
```

Because when using `?:` it needs to be assigned somewhere. You get same error when you write.

```
1;
```

Comment: Another way but not recommended `Convert.ToInt32(yn == "Y")` :)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how @m.kazem has explained it, However i usually apply brackets to indicate that a condition is being tested. E.g:

```
yes = (yn=="Y") ? 1 : 0;
```

So if `yn` equals "Y" set your integer to 1,else set it to 0